# Check processes of multiple servers in parallel with if statement

Tags: bash, process

I have a bash function which checks if there are any process running on servers by reading their IPs from a text file one by one

```
  while read IP
  do
    if [ 1 -eq "$(echo "$(ssh -n ubuntu@$IP "top -b -n2 -d 0.5|grep Cpu|awk '{print \$2+\$4}'|tail -n1") > 1.0" | bc)" ];then
      echo "process is running on $IP"
    else
      echo "process is not running on $IP"
    fi 
  done < file.ips
```

file.ips contains few server ips

```
202.X.X.X
203.X.X.X
204.X.X.X
...
...
...
```

I want to modify this function to check the process running on multiple servers parallelly

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel you can do:

```
check() {
  IP="$1"
  if [ 1 -eq "$(echo "$(ssh -n ubuntu@$IP "top -b -n2 -d 0.5|grep Cpu|awk '{print \$2+\$4}'|tail -n1") > 1.0" | bc)" ];then
    echo "process is running on $IP"
  else
    echo "process is not running on $IP"
  fi
}
export -f check
parallel -j0 check < file.ips
```

Answer (score 0):

---

What about running the content of the loop in the background?

```
  while read IP
  do
    (if [ 1 -eq "$(echo "$(ssh -n ubuntu@$IP "top -b -n2 -d 0.5|grep Cpu|awk '{print \$2+\$4}'|tail -n1") > 1.0" | bc)" ];then
      echo "process is running on $IP"
    else
      echo "process is not running on $IP"
    fi) & 
  done < file.ips
```